# How to call a jar by passing arguments from a java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I have a spring boot project and out of which i have created a jar, and i am calling this jar from another project by passing arguments.

Not able to get the output and it is getting stuck.

The below is the project from which i am getting a jar.

```
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("jar called");
        for(String arg : args) {
            System.out.println("next argument is"+ arg );
        }
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Its a simple spring boot main class.

The below is the class of another project from which i want to invoke this jar by passing arguments.

```
public class AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            File jarFile = new File("D:\\NewConfigWorkSpace\\Demo1\\target\\Demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar");

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar D:\\NewConfigWorkSpace\\Demo1\\target\\Demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar bisnu mohan");
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("finished");
    }

}
```

How to see the console when i am calling the jar, how to track how much execution has been happened.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the input stream of created process. This is what is normally returned to a console when you run your application.

```java
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar D:\\NewConfigWorkSpace\\Demo1\\target\\Demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar bisnu mohan");
InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
```

You can then read contents of it and print to a console of a running process like this:

```java
StringBuilder outputLines = new StringBuilder();
String output;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, UTF_8))) {
     String line;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           logger.info("Command execution output: " + line);
           outputLines.append(line).append("\n");
     }
} finally {
     output = outputLines.toString().trim();
}
```

It would also be a good idea to handle error stream the same way, because you can then see if your subprocess returns some errors.

```java
InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
```

Use this streams handling in a separate threads so they don't block each other.

Comment: this is working if the jar is a springBootApplication, but if it is a normal web application and there is no @SpringBootApplication, then its not working....why so...can you explain

Comment: If my jar application doesn't have @SpringBootApplication, then 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)) is coming as NULL...why so

Comment: public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("jar called");
  for(String arg : args) {
   System.out.println("next argument is"+ arg );
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you don't need to execute JAR via command line.

If you include JAR into your project you can just import `SpringApplication` from JAR and run it directly like this:

```
public class AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);    
    }
}
```

Comment: how to pass arguments?

Comment: and how to check the logs when the other jar is executing

Comment: as included JAR logic is executed in main your AAAAA.... process, it will contain all the logs. Concerning arguments, your AAAA... class will pass them into Spring application imported from JAR (as it is obvious from my code example)

Comment: Thats a springboot application, thats why SpringApplication.run will work...what if thats a simple java application.....

Comment: `SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args); ` call starts Spring application from "simple" java application.

Comment: public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("jar called");
  for(String arg : args) {
   System.out.println("next argument is"+ arg );
  }
 }
}

This is the jar i want to invoke

Comment: I am telling there is no @SpringBootApplication annotation.

The jar has been created from a java class

Comment: i have modified the question...please check